# Jquery Как найти самое маленькое число в строке у таблицы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таблица, не всегда в ней заполнены ячейки, тоесть есть пустые.
Как найти самое маленькое число в каждой из строк?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто: обходим все строки циклом, внутри которого обходим все ячейки и сравниваем их `.text()`. В конце обхода очередной строки имеем наименьшее из значений.

Код может выглядеть, например, вот так:

живой пример на jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ipshenicyn/51u348nc/

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
    var $tr = $(this);
    var smallest = null;

    $tr.find('td').each(function(){
        var number = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);          
        if(number && (smallest === null || smallest > number))
            smallest = number;
    });

    if(null !== smallest){
        $tr.find('.result').text(smallest);
    }
});
```

наименьшее значение я для примера записываю в специально отведенную для него последнюю ячейку каждой строки (выделено жирным).

Если вы растолкуете свой вопрос более детально - можно будет дать ответ, подходящий именно к вашей ситуации (если данный вариант вам не подходит).

Comment: Спасибо, уже получилось как надо.

Comment: ничего не тратил, модернизировал под себя, посмотрел на другой ответ что был выше (теперь он ниже, попытался разобраться), написал вам спасибо и опять посмотрел другой ответ (он находит во всей таблице и ктому же не работает), поэтому вам в плюс и закрыл вопрос.

Comment: Простите за резкость. Неверно вас понял. Решил, что вы имеете ввиду "уже не нужно, я все сделал".

Answer (score 0):

```js
var min = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

$('td').each(function(){
 if ($.isNumeric($(this).html()))
       if ($(this).html() < min)
         min = parseInt($(this).html());
});

alert(min);
```

```css
td {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="jsTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                5
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
            1    
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                4
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
            <td>
            6    
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```